# Is it possible to use functions inside of a application just like a module

Tags: executable, function-pointers, loadlibrary

Is it possible to use a executable (EXE) as a DLL file in your application.

Some kind of WIN32 API for this?

I'm not trying to detour any functions or patch anything to the file itself.

Something like LoadLibaray for EXE (well I know LoadLibaray loads the whole dll anyways, so if a eqivanlent loads whole exe I don't mind as long as it doesn't call main method to start the program up)

Since I have this program which does alot of work but I don't really want to load it all up.. it's huge.. I just want to call a few functions from inside of it is it possible?

LoadLibaray for EXE?

Can't really rip the functions out of the EXE as it's over 23,000~ lines of assembly and split in 160 functions.

Comment: Are the functions you want to call exported?

Comment: Well you could do it if they were exported. EXEs can export functions just as DLLs do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this. You can only reference DLLs if you are using Visual Studio. But if you are using csc.exe to compile your C# code, you can use the /R parameter and reference executables, but this is achieved through command line.

Comment: you can do it via visual studio too. It's just standard assembly referencing.

Comment: i have never referenced an exe. i can't find any documentation to support this either.

Comment: but how about in C++? can't I reference a EXE.. like load it up or something.. and call it's functions, I know the addresses for these functions.